# Replacing dynamic PHP files with static HTML files for better performance

Tags: php, html, caching

I was thinking of this to dynamically generate static versions of my websites files in order to increase performance.

So the index.html file (on my server .html files are parsed by PHP) does this when a user requests the file:

1. Requests itself using file_get_contents(). This gets the HTML that the user sees.
2. Renames itself (index.html) to index.html.orig and writes the HTML that it just retrieved to a new index.html file.

So future requests for index.html get the (now) static index.html and the dynamic index.html.orig justs sits there in case I need it.

If I need it to be re-cached I just delete the static index.html file and rename the index.html.orig file back to index.html (where it will soon be requested by someone again and re-cached.

To be honest I don't think my website is busy enough to warrant this, but I am quite bored.

I could also put a snippet like this at the top of each static file as it gets written:

```
<?php
    header('Cache-Control: public,private,max-age=604800'):
    header('Last-Modified: ...'):
    header('Expires: ...'):
?>
```

Comment: You can only cache based on `$_GET` and `$_POST` requirements, for example if you have a search that returns results, you would have to A. not cache that or B. include the request as something you can use to pull the cached file.

Comment: There are some very good methods of caching the final result of a PHP file already. Checkout [PHP OPcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.opcache.php), [PHP APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) and [Memcached](https://memcached.org/) ... They all provide solutions to easily cache pages, setting invalidating times and automatic query string differentiation.

Comment: But with this method PHP wouldn't be in the picture at all (if I didn't add those header() calls). Wouldn't that be better? EDIT Plus I can't change the server beyond using .htaccess files on my hosting.

Comment: @Richard - PHP will/should always have a hand in it, it becomes a maintenance issue if you just use HTML, what if you update something used on 1000 html pages, you have to re-make all those pages.  PHP can be used to automatically detect that and do it for you when needed.

Comment: Honestly with the performance of modern computers and broadband, you can usually optimize it enough to not need caching, in most cases.  Good bench marking and proper use of DB indexes can go a long way.

Comment: I don't see a real use of it, seriously. On a normal use-case, you want to have control over security and user accesses.

Comment: For example I had a query at work that was taking about 25 seconds to return, I changed all the OR conditions to a Union based sub-query and now it takes about 3 seconds.  And this is a query that Joins about 10 tables with probably 4 to 5 million total rows possible.

Comment: Completely alternatively, if you are seeking to use `.html` files only on your site, why not try your hand at a JavaScript / React static site generator such as [GatsbyJS](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/)? It will convert all your pages to .html files once you are finished. I can vouch that final products are usually lightening fast!

Comment: So much really depends on what type of site you have, how DB heavy it is and the specs of your server.  The server we use at work is 64GB ram and 8 quad core intel processors and 1TB SSD etc.  It's also in a DMZ with a reverse proxy server.  Which is a pain in the .... but that's security for you.

Comment: On my web server .html files are parsed by PHP so even if the file has no PHP directives in it the PHP module gets loaded and scans the file. Doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is have the file be `index.php` and set the web server to look for `index.html` first before `index.php`. That way in `index.php` you can use something like `ob_start()` and `ob_get_flush()` to output the contents of the file but also get it in a string so you can save it to `index.html`. Future requests will just load the HTML version.

Comment: So then why having an index.php file if users hit only the html one? How would you handle the index.html refresh? Who does that?

Comment: This seems to be what he was asking. He was going to delete `index.html` and rename `index.html.orig` back to `index.html` if he wanted to regenerate. I felt this would be easier because all he'd have to do is delete `index.html` and the next request would regenerate the cached version.

Comment: Ya ok that makes sense.